# Active Calories VS Total Calories during a workout

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, watchos, activity.app, apple-watch.app

I'm fairly new to the Apple App- I was a Fitbit user and Fitbit reflected Fat burn, active minutes and Peek time during a work out.  Apple app reflects Active Calories and Total Calories during a work out and I am not able to find an answer to define the difference.  what is the difference in a work out from Active vs Total.  I am still on the fence about this app, fitbit showed when during my work out my heartrate increased, and clearly reflected the calories -

Answer (score 2):

**Active calories** are a result of your activity (running, swimming, etc.) only.

**Total calories** take into account how many calories your body consumes during that period of time (just to keep you alive) as well as the active calories.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, active calories are those you burn while walking, climbing, jogging — whatever you do for exercise. Total calories include active calories and resting calories, which are those your body burns naturally, even when you're just lounging on the couch.

For instance, when I use a rowing machine at the gym, the meter attached to the rowing machine will estimate the number of calories I burned while rowing and, if that meter were an Apple Watch, those calories would be the active calories.  The rowing machine does not know your age/height/weight and thus cannot estimate your resting calories.

Answer (score 0):

Active calories is the calories you burn exercising.
Resting calories is the calories your body burn while resting. The energy to “function”.

Total calories is the sum of both.